# restrict user from tampering with the address url

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

i am creating a small web application using asp.net mvc3

```
http://localhost:1871/ManageMember/Admin/MemberDetail/3
```

for example i have the above url...as you can see that the parameter 3 is easily visible and can be changed by user and similarly can view the details regarding that particular id parameter

```
  http://localhost:1871/ManageMember/Admin/MemberDetail/5
```

I want to stop the user to tampering with the url

Comment: If you provide some obvious interface URL you need to check on the server side whether the user is qualified to read/see/access the information.

Comment: I've done this in firefox ...It is possible

Answer (score 2):

Impossible, unless you somehow mangle the 3 (i.e. have some mapping on the back end where `af320f32la0gw` -> `3` and `bof320afj2fw` -> `5`).  Then it would at least be very hard to *guess* the ID.

Other than that you would need some sort of authentication for viewing `3` or `5` initially.

Finally, *why* do you want to prevent people from doing this?  Seems like it could be handy for power users.

Answer (score 0):

IE allows you to lock the Address bar (not sure if other browsers support this).

But regardless of how easy, difficult, resticted or "mingled" the URL is, as E. Pills points out, server-side-enforced authorization would be mandatory (your code and URL structure implies that you already have authentication mechanism in place).

One way you could achieve this is to store server-side session token on initial authentication and verify all incoming request for proper authorization.

Answer (score 0):

```
if itIS == MVC
 use Request.ServerVariables["http_referer"]
else if itIS == webforms
 use HttpRequest.UrlReferrer
```